# How add new columns to the existing database on asset folder?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I have an application that use existing sqlite database on that and put my database on asset folder of android application. Now I need to add new columns to one of the table of database. I googled and find some questions and answers but none of them had same problem, Infact on table which I need to add new column on it there is useful data that I couldn't lost them. I attached my code as follow:

public class ExternalDbOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

```
    public static final int DATABASE_NEW_VERSION = 1;
public static final int DATABASE_OLD_VERSION = 1;

public static String DB_PATH;

private static String TABALE_NAME = "font";
private static String FONT_ID = "_id";
private static String FONT_TYPE = "font_type";
private static String FONT_SIZE = "font_size";

public static String DB_NAME;
public SQLiteDatabase database;
public final Context context;

public SQLiteDatabase getDb() {
    return database;
}

public ExternalDbOpenHelper(Context context, String databaseName) {
    super(context, databaseName, null, DATABASE_NEW_VERSION);
    this.context = context;

    String packageName = context.getPackageName();

    DB_PATH = String.format("//data//data//%s//databases//", packageName);
    DB_NAME = databaseName;
    openDataBase();
}


public void createDataBase() {
    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
    if (!dbExist) {
        this.getReadableDatabase();
        try {
            copyDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), "Copying error");
            throw new Error("Error copying database!");
        }
    } else {
        Log.i(this.getClass().toString(), "Database already exists");
    }
}

private boolean checkDataBase() {
    SQLiteDatabase checkDb = null;
    try {
        String path = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), "Error while checking db");
    }
    if (checkDb != null) {
        checkDb.close();
    }
    return checkDb != null;
}

private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

    InputStream externalDbStream = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    OutputStream localDbStream = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = externalDbStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        localDbStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
    localDbStream.close();
    externalDbStream.close();

}

public SQLiteDatabase openDataBase() throws SQLException {
    String path = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    if (database == null) {
        createDataBase();
        database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }
    return database;
}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {
    if (database != null) {
        database.close();
    }
    super.close();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {


}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}


public int updateFont(int i, String fontName, int p) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues font = new ContentValues();
    font.put(FONT_TYPE, fontName);
    font.put(FONT_SIZE, p);

    String whereClause = FONT_ID + " LIKE ?";
    String[] whereArgs = new String[] { String.valueOf(i) };

    db.update(TABALE_NAME, font, whereClause, whereArgs);
    return db.update(TABALE_NAME, font, whereClause, whereArgs);
    }
}
```

Comment: you can try increasing your database version, so that onUpgrade method is called and in that you can simply execute alter table queries to add new columns to existing table. Remember to add same alter table code in the method you copy your database from assets folder to apps database location to maintain integrity for future installs, if you do not wish to update the db residing inside your assets folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways, but they all start with increasing your `DATABASE_NEW_VERSION`.

Then your `onUpgrade()` method will be called on devices that have a version less than the one specified by `DATABASE_NEW_VERSION`. If you find yourself making multiple changes over time you can check if the device is multiple versions behind by looking at the `oldVersion` passed to this method.

The generic solution (if you start renaming tables, columns and generally remapping data) is just read the "old data" from database/table and store it in an `ArrayList` etc. Then `DROP` the old table(s), `CREATE` new table(s), and then `INSERT` the data.

However, if you're only adding new columns, it can be done simply with:

```
ALTER TABLE {tableName} ADD COLUMN {columnName} {type};
```

`ALTER TABLE` syntax [here](http://sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html).

Comment: Thank you for answering, I want add new columns to the table that is full with information and the folder didn't create on android app just created before and connect to my app. What will happen to my new user? How should I add the columns for them?

Comment: @user3752236 It looks like you're copying a database that is bundled in the apps assets directory. So if you simply update (on your machine) the database that your bundling with the app then new users will get a copy of that database instead. An alternative to copying the "database file" would instead by to load the data from the assets database and insert them into "db" in onCreate().

Answer (score 0):

first you need to save the contents of your table into a cursor. then create a new database with updated columns and put the values from the cursor.